# How do I draw line from the outer most arc of the circle

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

I am trying to draw the label line the outer most point of the circle like this picture.

[image]

```js
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .append("g")

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "slices");
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "labels");
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "lines");

var width = 960,
  height = 450,
  radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
  .sort(null)
  .value(function(d) {
    return d.value;
  });

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
  .outerRadius(radius * 0.8)
  .innerRadius(radius * 0.4);

var outerArc = d3.svg.arc()
  .innerRadius(radius * 0.9)
  .outerRadius(radius * 0.9);

svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var key = function(d) {
  return d.data.label;
};

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(["53% KILLED 2791", "dolor sit", "amet", "consectetur", "adipisicing", "elit", "sed", "do", "eiusmod", "tempor", "incididunt"])
  .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

function randomData() {
  var labels = color.domain();
  return labels.map(function(label) {
    return {
      label: label,
      value: Math.random()
    }
  });
}

change(randomData());

d3.select(".randomize")
  .on("click", function() {
    change(randomData());
  });


function change(data) {

  /* ------- PIE SLICES -------*/
  var slice = svg.select(".slices").selectAll("path.slice")
    .data(pie(data), key);

  slice.enter()
    .insert("path")
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return color(d.data.label);
    })
    .attr("class", "slice");

  slice
    .transition().duration(1000)
    .attrTween("d", function(d) {
      this._current = this._current || d;
      var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
      this._current = interpolate(0);
      return function(t) {
        return arc(interpolate(t));
      };
    })

  slice.exit()
    .remove();

  /* ------- TEXT LABELS -------*/

  var text = svg.select(".labels").selectAll("text")
    .data(pie(data), key);

  text.enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.data.label;
    });

  function midAngle(d) {
    return d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / 2;
  }

  text.transition().duration(1000)
    .attrTween("transform", function(d) {
      this._current = this._current || d;
      var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
      this._current = interpolate(0);
      return function(t) {
        var d2 = interpolate(t);
        var pos = outerArc.centroid(d2);
        pos[0] = radius * (midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
        return "translate(" + pos + ")";
      };
    })
    .styleTween("text-anchor", function(d) {
      this._current = this._current || d;
      var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
      this._current = interpolate(0);
      return function(t) {
        var d2 = interpolate(t);
        return midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? "start" : "end";
      };
    });

  text.exit()
    .remove();

  /* ------- SLICE TO TEXT POLYLINES -------*/

  var polyline = svg.select(".lines").selectAll("polyline")
    .data(pie(data), key);

  polyline.enter()
    .append("polyline");

  polyline.transition().duration(1000)
    .attrTween("points", function(d){
      this._current = this._current || d;
        console.log('_current = ' + JSON.stringify(this._current));
        console.log('d = ' + JSON.stringify(d));
      var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
        console.log('interpolate = ' + JSON.stringify(interpolate(0)));
      this._current = interpolate(0);
      return function(t) {
        var d2 = interpolate(t);
          console.log('t = ' + JSON.stringify(t));
        console.log('d2 = ' + JSON.stringify(d2));
        var pos = outerArc.centroid(d2);
        pos[0] = radius * 0.95 * (midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
        return [arc.centroid(d2), outerArc.centroid(d2), pos];
      };        
    }); 

  polyline.exit()
    .remove();
};
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  width: 960px;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

path.slice {
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

polyline {
  opacity: .3;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  fill: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
<button class="randomize">randomize</button>
```

I am new to D3 and not too sure how to calculate the points to achieve this. I tried looking up formulas what calculating circles but wasn't sure which formula is best for this situation.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: One easy solution would be appending the  g class lines before the slices

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Qh9X5/3136/ try this fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your code, you can see that the lines connecting the arc segments to the text is drawn by this code (near the end of your snippet):

```
return [arc.centroid(d2), outerArc.centroid(d2), pos];
```

It basically draws:

1. from the center of the segment, `arc.centroid(d2)` (which is drawn between the 0.4 to 0.8 of the `radius`)
2. makes a stop at the virtual outer arc, `outerArc.centroid(d2)` (which is drawn at 0.9) of the radius: this is where the line bends
3. and finally ends at `pos` where the text label is anchored at

So, if you want it to start outside the main pie chart, simply supply a new arc to the first argument. Let's give that arc a radius of `0.82`, for example:

```
var polylineStartArc = d3.svg.arc()
  .innerRadius(radius * 0.82)
  .outerRadius(radius * 0.82);
```

And then you ammend your polyline drawing logic with this:

```
return [polylineStartArc.centroid(d2), outerArc.centroid(d2), pos];
```

Of course, you can adjust this value between the range of 0.8 and 0.9:

- you want to keep it >0.8 so that it does not intersect with the pie chart
- you want to keep it <0.9 so that it does not go further out than the "bend" in the line

See proof-of-concept below:

```js
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .append("g")

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "slices");
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "labels");
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "lines");

var width = 960,
  height = 450,
  radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
  .sort(null)
  .value(function(d) {
    return d.value;
  });

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
  .outerRadius(radius * 0.8)
  .innerRadius(radius * 0.4);

var outerArc = d3.svg.arc()
  .innerRadius(radius * 0.9)
  .outerRadius(radius * 0.9);

var polylineStartArc = d3.svg.arc()
  .innerRadius(radius * 0.82)
  .outerRadius(radius * 0.82);

svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var key = function(d) {
  return d.data.label;
};

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(["53% KILLED 2791", "dolor sit", "amet", "consectetur", "adipisicing", "elit", "sed", "do", "eiusmod", "tempor", "incididunt"])
  .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

function randomData() {
  var labels = color.domain();
  return labels.map(function(label) {
    return {
      label: label,
      value: Math.random()
    }
  });
}

change(randomData());

d3.select(".randomize")
  .on("click", function() {
    change(randomData());
  });


function change(data) {

  /* ------- PIE SLICES -------*/
  var slice = svg.select(".slices").selectAll("path.slice")
    .data(pie(data), key);

  slice.enter()
    .insert("path")
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return color(d.data.label);
    })
    .attr("class", "slice");

  slice
    .transition().duration(1000)
    .attrTween("d", function(d) {
      this._current = this._current || d;
      var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
      this._current = interpolate(0);
      return function(t) {
        return arc(interpolate(t));
      };
    })

  slice.exit()
    .remove();

  /* ------- TEXT LABELS -------*/

  var text = svg.select(".labels").selectAll("text")
    .data(pie(data), key);

  text.enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.data.label;
    });

  function midAngle(d) {
    return d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / 2;
  }

  text.transition().duration(1000)
    .attrTween("transform", function(d) {
      this._current = this._current || d;
      var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
      this._current = interpolate(0);
      return function(t) {
        var d2 = interpolate(t);
        var pos = outerArc.centroid(d2);
        pos[0] = radius * (midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
        return "translate(" + pos + ")";
      };
    })
    .styleTween("text-anchor", function(d) {
      this._current = this._current || d;
      var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
      this._current = interpolate(0);
      return function(t) {
        var d2 = interpolate(t);
        return midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? "start" : "end";
      };
    });

  text.exit()
    .remove();

  /* ------- SLICE TO TEXT POLYLINES -------*/

  var polyline = svg.select(".lines").selectAll("polyline")
    .data(pie(data), key);

  polyline.enter()
    .append("polyline");

  polyline.transition().duration(1000)
    .attrTween("points", function(d){
      this._current = this._current || d;
      var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
      this._current = interpolate(0);
      return function(t) {
        var d2 = interpolate(t);
        var pos = outerArc.centroid(d2);
        pos[0] = radius * 0.95 * (midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
        return [polylineStartArc.centroid(d2), outerArc.centroid(d2), pos];
      };        
    }); 

  polyline.exit()
    .remove();
};
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  width: 960px;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

path.slice {
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

polyline {
  opacity: .3;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  fill: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
<button class="randomize">randomize</button>
```

Comment: thank you.  This is the answer that I am looking for!